# Why does Activity not have a onClick event handler?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm trying to have my activity respond to a single click but I cannot find a way to implement this.
I can use `onTouchEvent` override that method and have my logic run there but `onClick` is not possible?

What is the reason behind this and what could I do to get the desired effect that I want?

**As requested: what I currently have**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    pixelColor = Color.RED;

    PixelParticle pp = new PixelParticle(this, x, y, 50, 50, pixelColor);
    setContentView(pp); 

}
```

this isn't working - I implement `OnClickListener` and override the above method, the canvas never draws what I want it to draw.

Comment: you can have click listeners for the views.

Comment: Please, post code what have you tried.

Comment: let your Activity implement OnClickListener

Answer (score 2):

Touch down + touch up of the same point in a short time is a `onClick`(Actually onClick event in the android source code is really made in this way).

Because the `onTouchEvent`(in activity) is made for you to check touch event of the whole screen.But `onClick` is designed to check the click event on a view(not the whole screen).Touch event is the original event,click isn´t.

If you want to check whether your screen is clicked ,just use the `onClick` method of your layout(give it an id myLayout).

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
layout.setOnClickListener(xxx);
```